# Pass Touch Events through Overlay

Tags: javascript, react-native, touch-event, react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

**Setup**

I have 2 screens, let us call them A and B.

Screen A is showing the camera image recorded by the back camera of the phone (third party library which i do not have further access to).
Screen B has a semi transparent background and some UI elements (e.g. Buttons)

[image]

**Task**

I can not add UI elements to Screen A directly (third party) that's why i'm using [react-native-navigation V2](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/tree/v2) to overlay Screen B via [Navigation.showOverlay](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/v2/#/docs/top-level-api?id=showoverlaylayout-) on top of Screen A.

**Problem**

Both screens need to react to touch events but it seems like the overlay of Screen B blocks these events on Screen A.

[image]

**Question**

Is it somehow possible to pass all touch events down from Screen B (UI with Overlay) to Screen A (Camera Screen which also needs to react to touch events) so that both screens are capable of reacting to user input?

---

In case someone is interested in the third party component i'm talking about: https://github.com/brave-digital/react-native-wikitude/issues/10

Comment: Interesting use case. I'm assuming Screen B contains components at the bottom and the top of the screen. Perhaps you can split screen B into two Overlays, one at the top and the other at the bottom. This way they wouldn't prevent Screen A from handling touch events (use interceptTouchOutside: false)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using react-native-navigation showOverlay, use can use

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <ScreenA />
  <View style={{position: "absolute", height: screenHeight, width: screenWidth}} pointerEvents={'box-none'}>
    <ScreenB />
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: this should work but we are using react native navigation, so we must use Modal to represent ScreenB.

Answer (score 1):

When showing the Navigation overlay, you can use its options to control touch interception.
Try to configure it like so, and notice the `interceptTouchOutside` overlay option:

```
Navigation.showOverlay({
  component: {
    id: 'myComponent',
    name: 'myComponent',
    passProps,
    options: {
      layout: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        componentBackgroundColor: 'transparent'
      },
      overlay: {
        interceptTouchOutside: false
      }
    }
  }
});
```

If you're rendering a full screen, you might also need to set its topmost view `pointerEvents` prop (on `myComponent` in the example above).

Comment: tried that but still ScreenA buttons doesn't get clicked. I think RNN Modal doesn't care about `pointerEvents`...

Comment: I had a very similar use case and this solution worked. If you can post a more complete example I can maybe look into it

Comment: @leo7r regarding pointerEvents - it is still relevant also in this case. The overlay option I mentioned prevents the overlay window from intercepting touches, but you still have the View that you render inside the overlay which prevents touches from propagating to any other views below

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use a button/touchable opacity to open the camera screen using a function (to bring it into focus..) This way both screens could receive user inputs.

The function to open the other screen as a new instance would probably be the best bet at both screens reacting to user input independently.

The code below is sample code that could be put in such a button/touchable opacity on the UI screen.

e.g `<Button onPress = { this.fnOpenCamera } title = 'Camera View'/>`

```
fnOpenCamera = () =>
 {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenA');

 }
```

Answer (score -4):

try prop pointerEvents='box-none' or refer [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12360) issue